# How to fix "no previous regular expression" error when running a 'sed' command?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to run the following expression in a script to find a device and change one of the fields associated with the device in an HTML file.

```
sed -e "s/$OLDTEST/$TESTING/" -e "s/$CURRENTVALU/$NEWSTATUS---$DATE/" -e "s/$PASSORFAIL/$PASSORFAILNEW/" -e "s/$BGCOLOR/$BGCOLORNEW/$POSITION"  -e "s/$OLDNOTE/$NOTE/"  >> //sysadm/shared/file.tmp
```

I seem to keep getting a "no previous regular expression". Any ideas?

debug log output:

```
sed -e s//Yes/ -e s//Resolved---03-25-13/ -e s//Pass/ -e s//#348017/1 -e s///

sed: -e expression #5, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

Comment: Are you trying to replace a literal sequence of e.g. `$OLDTEST` in your source file, or are OLDTEST, TESTING, etc. variables that contain things you're searching for/replacing? If the former, use single quotes to prevent expansion, if the latter, we'll need to know what those variables contain...

Comment: I'm trying to search for an sequence and then once I find it I replace all the items associated with it

Comment: while read LINE
do
 if
  echo $LINE |grep $ROUTER  > /dev/null 2>&1
 then
  CURRENTVALU=`echo $LINE |awk '{print $53}'| sed 's/ //'`
  echo $LINE | sed -e "s/$OLDTEST/$TESTING/" -e "s/$CURRENTVALU/$NEWSTATUS---$DATE/" -e "s/$PASSORFAIL/$PASSORFAILNEW/" -e "s/$BGCOLOR/$BGCOLORNEW/$POSITION"  -e "s/$OLDNOTE/$NOTE/"  >> /sysadmin/shared/file.tmp

Comment: elif
  echo $LINE |grep Devices > /dev/null 2>&1
 then
  echo $LINE | sed -e "s/$CURRENTDEV/$DEV/" -e "s/$CURRENTTOTAL/$TOTAL/" -e "s/$CURRENTPASS/$PASS/" -e "s/$CURRENTFAIL/$FAIL/" -e  "s/$CURRENTPCNT/$PERCNT/" >> /sysadmin/shared/file.tmp
 else
  echo $LINE >> /sysadmin/shared/file.tmp
 fi
done  < /sysadmin/shared/file.tmp

Comment: That's the complete while loop I'm using, hopefully that helps to clarify a bit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your debugging log is telling you the whole story ;-)

```
sed -e s//Yes/ -e s//Resolved---03-25-13/ -e s//Pass/ -e s//#348017/1 -e s///
 #------^-- empty regular expression
```

Hence the error message `"no previous regular expression".`

Not clear about your experience, so there are 2 solutions. Recall that in unix/linux based shells, strings inside of dbl-quotes will be evaluated for variable substitution and that your code, `"s/$OLDTEST/$TESTING/"` looks like a string requiring variable substitution.

You may need to do

```
export OLDTEST="something old"
export TESTING="something new"
```

for that code to work.

If you really want the literal string '$OLDTEST' to be substituted with the literal string '$TESTING', then you have to "hide' the variables from the shell processing. We do that in unix/linux by using the single quote chars., so then your commands would be

```
sed 's/$OLDTEST/$TESTING/
     s/$CURRENTVALU/$NEWSTATUS---$DATE/
     s/$PASSORFAIL/$PASSORFAILNEW/
     s/$BGCOLOR/$BGCOLORNEW/$POSITION
     s/$OLDNOTE/$NOTE/'  >> //sysadm/shared/file.tmp
```

But.. I don't see an input file here.

so its really

```
sed 's/ ...../..../ ; s/../..../; etc; s/.../../' inputFile >> //sysadm/shared/file.tmp
```

AND you probably don't really want to append to an existing file for something with a tmp extension, so ...

```
sed 's/ ...../..../ ; s/../..../; etc; s/.../../' inputFile > //sysadm/shared/file.tmp
#-----------------------------------------------only one > -^-------
```

Using `>>` means as your testing enhancing your sed script, your appending the results of each run into the same file. You'll wind up with a lot of duplicate info.

I've used the sed shorthand, omitting the `-e` option. Sed can process a whole group of cmds as one argument as I show here. You could also put all of those commands into a separate file, and then call it like

```
   sed -f fixer.sed inputFile > //sysadmin/shared/file.tmp
```

AND finally, if your `sed` supports the `-i` option, you can 'in-line' your changes and just have

```
sed -i -f fixer.sed inputFile
```

And sed will overwrite the old file with the changes. I'd recommend against this until you're certain that all changes your attempting work and don't cause any unintended consequences. Once your original file is gone, there's no getting it back, so saving to .tmp as your are doing is a good safety belt:-)

IHTH

Comment: I'm doing an echo $LINE | sed, so the $LINE is my input.  Thanks for the input, I'll have to process this.

Comment: Even with your expanded code sample, I don't see where you're setting a value for OLDTEST, etc. You may or maynot need the `export`, but you definitely need either `OLDTEST="xyz"` or something in your while loop like `echo "$LINE" | while read OLDTEST var2 .... rest` ; do .... ; done` . It would be a lot easier for us to answer if all your code was in the main question. Consider editing. Use the {} edit tool near top left of edit-box to format your code. Good luck.